# PHP Domxpath How to get plain text that not inside a tag in an object

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

So, I have an HTML like this.

```
<p> 
  Example Text 1
  <span> Text </span>
  Example Text 2
  <img src="example.png">
</p>
```

I find and save every object inside that **p** tag like this.

```
$subObjects = $xpath->evaluate("*", $object);
```

But I want to get also "Example Text 1" and "Example Text 2" in order like tags.
How can I get these plain texts like a tag via using PHP DomXPATH? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `text()` function to your XPath query:

```php
$subObjects = $xpath->evaluate("*|text()", $object);
```